# Does validation using ng-pattern violate separation of concerns?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using ng-pattern on an input text field to check if the user entered a valid contact number (the first digit has to start with 6, 8 or 9, and has to have a total of 8 digits; I'm in Singapore). I've implemented a solution using a simple regex, but I'm wondering doesn't this violate SoC since the regex logic is in the view?

```
      <input ng-model='user.number' ng-pattern='/[689]\d{7}/' />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

Why don't you use a scope variable binded to a config file ?

conf.js :

```
angular.module('app.constant', [])
.constant('CONF', {
    pattern: '/[689]\d{7}/'
});
```

app.js - in controller :

```
scope.pattern = CONF.pattern;
```

html:

```
<input ng-model='user.number' ng-pattern='pattern' />
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about that option!